# ASP.NET Core w/ EF Core API returning "Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection." From Postman Get request

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, https

As an exercise in learning EF Core with C#/ASP.NET Core, I went through this tutorial to the end: [ASP.NET Core Web API with EF Core Code-First Approach](https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-api-ef-core-code-first/).

Once I finished I was able to go and run `'dotnet watch run'` from the source folder, and loading up the end point `http://localhost:5000/api/employee` I was able to get back a response in Chrome, from a redirect to the `https://localhost:5001/api/employee` endpoint.

I'm stuck because I want to get that same response in Postman, but I'm just seeing the following:

[image: Postman response]

This is what I see from Powershell where I'm running the server:

```
PS C:\Users\foo\source\repos\EFCoreCodeFirstSample\EFCoreCodeFirstSample> dotnet watch run
watch : Started
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\C M\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\foo\source\repos\EFCoreCodeFirstSample\EFCoreCodeFirstSample
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
dbug: HttpsConnectionAdapter[1] 
      Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__51_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
```

Everything from

```
dbug: HttpsConnectionAdapter[1] 
      Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection
```

and below shows up when I run the Postman Get request. I'm guessing it has something to do with how my startup.cs is configured... but I'm not sure where to start. Searching on Stack Overflow here got me a lot of questions regarding SSL certs, and pfx files, but nothing pertaining to this issue in particular. I'm new to this and in school, so maybe I simply missed the answer because it's beyond my scope of knowledge at this point? I don't understand why it would work in chrome, but not Postman.

Comment: This was solved by turning off SSL certificate verification in Postman, but if anyone could help me figure out where to start on SSL Cert verification, It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Hope this is local dev certificate. Have you tried by - `dotnet dev-certs https --help` and trust your certificate?
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx